# Infowise validation on Sharepoint

Tags: validation, sharepoint

Does anyone know anything about Infowise on Sharepoint?  I am trying to create a validation rule or figure out how to use the operators 'and' and 'or', but am having trouble.  I apologize for my question being vague, but I don't want to waste your time.  If someone knows how to use these operators with Infowise, please let me know and I can be more specific..

Live Long and Prosper.

Comment: Have you thought of asking the vendor for support? At the very least tell us which of one of the dozen infowise products you're asking about!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infowise does not support the use of and and or in the ways you like.